# Unity android plugin using AlarmManager

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, alarmmanager

is there any way of use an Android Alarm in a Unity Project?

I've tried creating my own .jar and creating my own activitie that extends UnityPlayerActivity. In the OnCreate method I write this code:

```
        Log.i("ALARM", "create alarm");
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)getBaseContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent AlarmIntent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmCheckStats.class);
    PendingIntent sender = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 0, AlarmIntent, 0);
    long repeat=2*1000;
    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis(),repeat, sender);
```

The log message is showing on LogCat, but then in never gets into the Alarm.onReceive. I declare the receiver correctly in Manifest.xml so I don´t know why is not working. Is there anybody that make something similar on Unity?